# Downloading localize packages at runtime

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have an app on the market, I would like to localize it to other languages, the process I would like to implement is:

1. User downloads the app
2. User selects language
3. **language pack is downloaded to applications folder**

my question is how to implement step #3 (and does it effect the app review process) using adobe air

Thanks

Comment: I think you should download a bundle with your translations as usual (localizable strings) and then use NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle

Comment: You can use Resource Bundles - they are designed to do exactly what you need (and no, they wont affect app review). See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcf.html

Comment: Thanks Lee, I am not sure I understand how the Resource Bundles work on mobile apps, will the released sources change according to client local? the way i understood it is that all swcs are downloaded to device and at runtime the correct language package is loaded, but all language are downloaded (just my assumption). p.s great blog

Answer (score 0):

Download your bundle to Documents directory with name "Translations.bundle", then use this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths firstObject];

NSString *bundlePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Translations.bundle"];

NSBundle *translationsBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSString *message = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Message", nil, translationsBundle, nil);
```

Comment: Thanks stotoj , I was actually looking for a way to implement this coding in adobe air.

Comment: Sorry "adobe air" was the last word, did not notice that. I'd like you to edit your question with "adobe air" bold :)